# Change Struts2 interceptor error messages

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I am using Struts 2 + Hibernate (full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2), and I have this code to check if image to upload is png:

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
    <package name="mypack" namespace="/" extends="hibernate-default">          
       ...
       <action name="myaction" class="com.actions.MyAction" >
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStackHibernate">
                <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">image/png</param>
            </interceptor-ref>            
            <result name="success" type="tiles" >baseLayout</result>
            <result name="error" type="tiles" >error</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles" >baseLayout</result>
        </action>
        ...
    </package>
</struts>
```

The error message that comes out if I upload not allowed image types is:

> Content-Type not allowed: image "img.jpg" "upload__2988a871_13b93535e21__7fc1_00000009.tmp" image/jpeg

How can I modify that error message? Using something like "hibernate-messages.properties"?

Comment: This is not related to Hibernate at all.

Comment: I thought that using Hibernate plugin things were different! But I was wrong..

Comment: `defaultStackHibernate` just adds some interceptors to stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this message by creating text for this key:

```
struts.messages.error.content.type.not.allowed
```